# Movie where two people meet and fall in love in a dream

Tags: story-identification, movie

Two people meet and fall in love in a dream. They return to each other each night. At the end they come together in real life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Copy/pasting the title brings up "[In My Dreams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_My_Dreams_(film)#:~:text=Natalie%20and%20Nick%20fall%20asleep,about%20the%20real%2Dfeeling%20dream.)" with a very similar summary. Is that it?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [Paperhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paperhouse_(film))

> While suffering from glandular fever, 11-year-old Anna Madden draws a house. When she falls asleep, she has disturbing dreams in which she finds herself inside the house she has drawn. After she draws a face at the window, in her next dream she finds Marc, a boy who suffers with muscular dystrophy, living in the house. She learns from her doctor that Marc is a real person.

Answer (score 0):

As Wondercricket noted in a comment, this could be Hallmark film [*In My Dreams*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_My_Dreams_(film))

> Nick Smith and Natalie Russo are single, living in the same city. On opposite sides of a fountain, they are both encouraged to make a wish. Their coins touch underwater, and they both feel odd.

....

> Natalie and Nick fall asleep in their respective living rooms and dream about meeting at the Hayward Fountain. They introduce themselves and have instant chemistry, but when they touch they both awaken.
>
> The next day, at the restaurant, Natalie tells Sharla about the real-feeling dream. Although Sharla's cousin is interested, she doesn't care. Sharla is drawn to Mario, and Natalie isn't. He reminds Natalie their mothers had been friends in Italy, and passes on his mother's condolences.

....

> Nick arrives to the fountain first, accidentally dropping the invite. Natalie misses him, but finds it and heads to the ceremony. He seeks her by visiting every Italian restaurant in town. Nick finds Russos, but Sharla doesn't know where Natalie is. Joe at the ceremony can't help her either. Both go the fountain, find each other and kiss.

### Trailer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "On Body and Soul"?
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5607714/

The movie is about two people (Endre and Mária) who work at the same slaughterhouse and share each night the same dream. In the dream, they meet in a forest as deer and fall in love. As the movie progresses they discover that connection and come together in real life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you [edit] your answer to include the details of this that make you believe it's a good match for the question?